# how do I match up array length when scraping data from a website (metacritc) Python

Tags: python, arrays, web-scraping

I'm running into an issue when I try to scape data from a webpage (metacritc), some of the data is not there

```
print(len(names))
print(len(metascores))
print(len(userscores))
print(len(release_datesNew))
print(len(publishers))
print(len(ratings))

109
105
103
109
100
33
```

as you can see from the above I'm getting different array lengths when I scrape the data with this code:

```
#Define year
year_number = 2018

# Define the URL
i = range(0, 1)

names = []
metascores = []
userscores = []
userscoresNew = []
release_dates = []
release_datesNew = []
publishers = []
ratings = []
genres = []
genresNew = []




for element in i:

    url = "http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/score/metascore/year/pc/filtered?view=detailed&sort=desc&year_selected=" + format(year_number)
    print(url)
    year_number -= 1
    # not sure about this but it works (I was getting blocked by something and this the way I found around it)
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    web_byte = urlopen(req).read()

    webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')

    #this grabs the all the text from the page
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html5lib')

    #this is for selecting all the games in from 1 to 100 (the list of them)
    game_names = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="main_stats")
    game_metas = html_soup.find_all("a", class_="basic_stat product_score")  
    game_users = html_soup.find_all("li", class_='stat product_avguserscore')
    game_releases = html_soup.find_all("ul", class_='more_stats')
    game_publishers = html_soup.find_all("li", class_='stat publisher')
    game_ratings = html_soup.find_all("li", class_='stat maturity_rating')
    game_genres = html_soup.find_all("li", class_='stat genre')



    #Extract data from each game
    for games in game_names:
        name = games.find()
        names.append(name.text.strip())
    else:
        names.append("NA")


    for games2 in game_metas:
        metascore = games2.find()
        metascores.append(metascore.text.strip())
    else:
        metascore.append("NA")

    for games3 in game_releases:
        release_date = games3.find()
        release_dates.append(release_date.text.strip())
    else:
        release_dates.append("NA")

    for games4 in game_users:
        userscore  = games4.find('span', class_="data textscore textscore_favorable") or games4.find('span', class_="data textscore textscore_mixed")
        if userscore:
            userscores.append(userscore.text)
        else:
            userscores.append("NA")

    for games5 in game_publishers:
        publisher = games5.find("span", class_ = "data")
        if publisher:
            publishers.append(publisher.text)
        else:
                publishers.append("NA")

    for games6 in game_ratings:
        rating = games6.find("span", class_ = "data")
        if rating:
            ratings.append(rating.text)
        else:
            userscores.append("NA")

    for games7 in game_genres:
        genre = games7.find("span", class_ = "data")
        if genre:
            genres.append(genre.text)
        else:
            genres.append("NA")


for x in release_dates:
    temp = str(x)
    temp2 = temp.replace("Release Date:\n                        ", "")
    release_datesNew.append(temp2)

for z in genres:
    temp3 = str(z)
    temp4 = temp3.strip()
    temp5 = temp4.replace("                                                            ", "")
    genresNew.append(temp5)

# df = pd.DataFrame({'Games:': names,
#                     'Metascore:': metascores,
#                     'Userscore:': userscores,
#                     'Release date:': release_datesNew,
#                     'Publisher:': publishers,
#                     'Rating:': ratings,
#                     'Genre:': genresNew}) 

# df.to_csv("metacritic scrape.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame({'Games:': names})
```

How can I write it so that when the game names are scraped if there is no value for the (or it's not there) other arrays it puts a place holder for that value (NA for example)

can't seem to figure it out

Update:

this is the code I have and is giving me an error

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests, contextlib, re
@contextlib.contextmanager
def get_page(page_num = 1, year = 2018):
    d = soup(requests.get(f'http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/score/metascore/year/pc/filtered?view=detailed&sort=desc&year_selected={year}&page={page_num-1}'), 'html.parser').find('ol', {'class':'list_products'}).find_all('li', {'class':'product'})
    headers = [['h3', 'product_title', False], ['span', 'metascore_w', False], ['span', 'data', True]]
    new_results = [[(lambda x:[re.sub('\n|\s{2,}', '', i.text) for i in x] if isinstance(x, list) else getattr(x, 'text', 'N/A'))(getattr(i, ['find', 'find_all'][c])(a, {'class':b})) for a, b, c in headers] for i in d]
    yield new_results

for i in range(1):
    with get_page(page_num = i) as results:
        print(results)
```

this is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bd8574826c21> in <module>()
      9 
     10 for i in range(1):
---> 11     with get_page(page_num = i) as results:
     12         print(results)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __enter__(self)
     79     def __enter__(self):
     80         try:
---> 81             return next(self.gen)
     82         except StopIteration:
     83             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None

<ipython-input-1-bd8574826c21> in get_page(page_num, year)
      3 @contextlib.contextmanager
      4 def get_page(page_num = 1, year = 2018):
----> 5     d = soup(requests.get(f'http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/score/metascore/year/pc/filtered?view=detailed&sort=desc&year_selected={year}&page={page_num-1}'), 'html.parser').find('ol', {'class':'list_products'}).find_all('li', {'class':'product'})
      6     headers = [['h3', 'product_title', False], ['span', 'metascore_w', False], ['span', 'data', True]]
      7     new_results = [[(lambda x:[re.sub('\n|\s{2,}', '', i.text) for i in x] if isinstance(x, list) else getattr(x, 'text', 'N/A'))(getattr(i, ['find', 'find_all'][c])(a, {'class':b})) for a, b, c in headers] for i in d]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py in __init__(self, markup, features, builder, parse_only, from_encoding, exclude_encodings, **kwargs)
    190         if hasattr(markup, 'read'):        # It's a file-type object.
    191             markup = markup.read()
--> 192         elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
    193                 (isinstance(markup, bytes) and not b'<' in markup)
    194                 or (isinstance(markup, str) and not '<' in markup)

TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a header with all tags and class names you wish to scrape:

```
from bs4 import BeautfulSoup as soup
import requests, contextlib, re
@contextlib.contextmanager
def get_page(page_num = 1, year = 2018):
   d = soup(requests.get(f'http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/score/metascore/year/pc/filtered?view=detailed&sort=desc&year_selected={year}&page={page_num-1}'), 'html.parser').find('ol', {'class':'list_products'}).find_all('li', {'class':'product'})
   headers = [['h3', 'product_title', False], ['span', 'metascore_w', False], ['span', 'data', True]]
   new_results = [[(lambda x:[re.sub('\n|\s{2,}', '', i.text) for i in x] if isinstance(x, list) else getattr(x, 'text', 'N/A'))(getattr(i, ['find', 'find_all'][c])(a, {'class':b})) for a, b, c in headers] for i in d]
   yield new_results

for i in range(1):
  with get_page(page_num = i) as results:
    print(results)
```

Output (first page):

```
[['Into the Breach', '89', ['Feb 27, 2018', 'Subset Games', '7.6']], ['Pillars of Eternity II: Deadfire', '88', ['May 8, 2018', 'M', 'Obsidian Entertainment, Versus Evil', 'Role-Playing,Western-Style', '7.8']], ['Celeste', '88', ['Jan 25, 2018', 'Matt Makes Games Inc.', 'Action,Platformer,2D', '7.0']], ['Subnautica', '87', ['Jan 23, 2018', 'E10+', 'Unknown Worlds Entertainment', 'Adventure,General', '8.2']], ['Iconoclasts', '87', ['Jan 23, 2018', 'Bifrost Entertainment', 'Action Adventure,Open-World', '7.3']], ['Final Fantasy XII: The Zodiac Age', '85', ['Feb 1, 2018', 'T', 'Square Enix', 'Role-Playing,Japanese-Style', '5.9']], ['Final Fantasy XV: Windows Edition', '85', ['Mar 6, 2018', 'T', 'Square Enix', 'Role-Playing,Action RPG', '7.2']], ['Dragon Ball FighterZ', '85', ['Jan 26, 2018', 'T', 'Bandai Namco Games', 'Action,2D,Fighting', '7.8']], ['Batman: The Enemy Within - Episode 5: Same Stitch', '85', ['Mar 26, 2018', 'Telltale Games', 'Adventure,Point-and-Click', '8.1']], ['Full Metal Furies', '85', ['Jan 17, 2018', 'Cellar Door Games', "Action,2D,Beat-'Em-Up", '7.0']], ['Frostpunk', '84', ['Apr 24, 2018', 'M', '11 bit studios, Merge Games', 'Action Adventure,Survival', '8.5']], ['Sprint Vector', '84', ['Feb 8, 2018', 'Survios', 'Racing,Other,Arcade', '6.6']], ['Total War: WARHAMMER II - Rise of the Tomb Kings', '84', ['Jan 23, 2018', 'Sega', '7.2']], ['The Elder Scrolls Online: Summerset', '84', ['May 21, 2018', 'M', 'Bethesda Softworks', '7.4']], ["Yoku's Island Express", '84', ['May 29, 2018', 'E10+', 'Villa Gorilla', 'Action,Pinball', '7.3']], ['The Forest', '83', ['Apr 30, 2018', 'SKS Games, Endnight Studios', 'Action Adventure,Horror,Horror,Survival', '7.2']], ['Warhammer: Vermintide 2', '82', ['Mar 8, 2018', 'Fatshark AB, Fatshark', 'Action,First-Person,Shooter,Arcade', '7.5']], ['The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim VR', '81', ['Apr 2, 2018', 'M', 'Bethesda Softworks', 'Role-Playing,Western-Style', '6.7']], ['CHUCHEL', '81', ['Mar 7, 2018', 'Amanita Design', 'Adventure,General', '7.5']], ['Ni no Kuni II: Revenant Kingdom', '81', ['Mar 23, 2018', 'T', 'Level 5, Bandai Namco Games', '7.9']], ['The Red Strings Club', '81', ['Jan 22, 2018', 'Devolver Digital', '7.9']], ['Guns, Gore & Cannoli 2', '80', ['Mar 2, 2018', 'Crazy Monkey Studios', 'Action,Third-Person,Shooter,Arcade', '7.2']], ['A Way Out', '80', ['Mar 23, 2018', 'M', 'Electronic Arts', 'Action,Action Adventure,General', '7.7']], ['Space Invaders Extreme', '79', ['Feb 12, 2018', 'Degica', 'tbd']], ['FAR: Lone Sails', '79', ['May 17, 2018', 'Mixtvision', '7.9']], ['Minit', '79', ['Apr 3, 2018', 'Devolver Digital', 'Adventure,General', '7.1']], ["Sid Meier's Civilization VI: Rise and Fall", '79', ['Feb 8, 2018', '2K Games', '6.1']], ['Far Cry 5', '79', ['Mar 27, 2018', 'M', 'Ubisoft', 'Action,First-Person,Shooter,Arcade', '6.0']], ['For the King', '78', ['Apr 19, 2018', 'IronOak Games', 'Role-Playing,Roguelike', 'tbd']], ['BattleTech', '78', ['Apr 24, 2018', 'Harebrained Schemes LLC', 'Strategy,Turn-Based,Tactics', '7.1']], ['Sairento VR', '78', ['Jan 19, 2018', 'Mixed Realms Pte Ltd', 'Action,Shooter,Light Gun', '8.0']], ['Pit People', '78', ['Mar 2, 2018', 'The Behemoth', 'Action,Strategy,Turn-Based,General,Tactics', '7.7']], ['Brass Tactics', '78', ['Feb 22, 2018', 'Hidden Path Entertainment']], ['Moonlighter', '78', ['May 29, 2018', 'E10+', '11 bit studios', 'Role-Playing,Action RPG', '7.5']], ['Legendary Gary', '78', ['Feb 20, 2018', 'Evan Rogers', 'tbd']], ['Ancestors Legacy', '77', ['May 22, 2018', '1C Company', 'Strategy,Real-Time,General', '8.1']], ['Remothered: Tormented Fathers', '77', ['Jan 30, 2018', 'M', 'Stormind Games', '7.8']], ['Dead In Vinland', '77', ['Apr 12, 2018', 'Playdius', '7.7']], ['A Case of Distrust', '77', ['Feb 8, 2018', 'Serenity Forge', 'tbd']], ['Batman: The Enemy Within - Episode 4: What Ails You', '77', ['Jan 22, 2018', 'Telltale Games', 'Adventure,Point-and-Click', '7.9']], ['Cultist Simulator', '76', ['May 31, 2018', 'Weather Factory', 'Strategy,Turn-Based,Card Battle', '6.6']], ['Kerbal Space Program: Making History', '76', ['Mar 13, 2018', 'Squad', 'tbd']], ['A Total War Saga: Thrones of Britannia', '76', ['May 2, 2018', 'Sega Europe', 'Strategy,Real-Time,General', '5.4']], ['Forgotton Anne', '76', ['May 15, 2018', 'Square Enix', 'Adventure,General', '8.0']], ['Aegis Defenders', '76', ['Feb 8, 2018', 'GUTS Department', 'Role-Playing,Action RPG']], ['Q.U.B.E. 2', '76', ['Mar 13, 2018', 'E', 'Toxic Games', 'Action,First-Person,Shooter,Arcade', '7.7']], ['Candleman: The Complete Journey', '76', ['Jan 31, 2018', 'Spotlightor Interactive', 'Action,Platformer,3D', '8.0']], ['Surviving Mars', '76', ['Mar 15, 2018', 'E10+', 'Paradox Interactive', 'Strategy,Management,Government', '6.3']], ['Kingdom Come: Deliverance', '76', ['Feb 13, 2018', 'M', 'Warhorse Studios', 'Role-Playing,Action Adventure,General,Action RPG,Historic', '8.0']], ['Solo', '76', ['Apr 26, 2018', 'Team Gotham', '6.2']], ['Tower of Time', '76', ['Apr 12, 2018', 'Event Horizon Software', '8.3']], ['Ghost of a Tale', '75', ['Mar 13, 2018', 'Ghost of a Tale, SeithCG', '8.3']], ['Monster Prom', '75', ['Apr 27, 2018', 'Those Awesome Guys', 'Adventure,General', '8.1']], ['Where the Water Tastes Like Wine', '75', ['Feb 28, 2018', 'Dim Bulb Games', 'Miscellaneous,General', '5.1']], ['Railway Empire', '74', ['Jan 26, 2018', 'E', 'Kalypso', 'Simulation,Train,Vehicle', '6.5']], ['Nantucket', '74', ['Jan 18, 2018', 'Fish Eagle', '7.5']], ['Vampyr', '74', ['Jun 4, 2018', 'M', 'Focus Home Interactive', 'Role-Playing,General,Action RPG', '7.2']], ['The Swords of Ditto', '74', ['Apr 24, 2018', 'E10+', 'Devolver Digital', 'Role-Playing,Action RPG', '6.7']], ['Jurassic World Evolution', '74', ['Jun 12, 2018', 'T', 'Frontier Developments', 'Strategy,Management,Business / Tycoon', '8.1']], ['Omensight', '74', ['May 15, 2018', 'Spearhead Games', 'First-Person,Adventure,3D', '7.7']], ['Tesla vs Lovecraft', '73', ['Jan 26, 2018', '10tons', 'tbd']], ['Apocalipsis', '73', ['Mar 1, 2018', 'PlayWay', 'tbd']], ['The Council - Episode 1: The Mad Ones', '73', ['Mar 13, 2018', 'M', 'Focus Home Interactive', '7.2']], ['Downward Spiral: Horus Station', '73', ['May 31, 2018', '3rd Eye Studios', 'First-Person,Adventure,3D', 'tbd']], ['The Fall Part 2: Unbound', '73', ['Feb 13, 2018', 'T', 'Over The Moon', 'Action Adventure,General', 'tbd']], ['Rad Rodgers', '73', ['Feb 21, 2018', 'M', '3D Realms', 'Action,Platformer,2D', '6.9']], ['Fe', '73', ['Feb 16, 2018', 'E', 'Electronic Arts', 'Action,General', '5.4']], ['Stellaris: Apocalypse', '73', ['Feb 22, 2018', 'Paradox Interactive', '6.9']], ['All Walls Must Fall', '72', ['Feb 23, 2018', 'inbetweengames', 'tbd']], ['The Station', '72', ['Feb 20, 2018', 'The Station', 'First-Person,Adventure,3D', '6.6']], ['Warhammer 40,000: Inquisitor - Martyr', '72', ['Jun 5, 2018', 'Games Workshop', 'Strategy,Real-Time,General', '8.0']], ['City of Brass', '71', ['May 4, 2018', 'Uppercut Games Pty Ltd', 'Action Adventure,General', '4.0']], ['Attack of the Earthlings', '71', ['Feb 8, 2018', 'Junkfish Limited', '6.8']], ['Light Fall', '71', ['Apr 26, 2018', 'Bishop Games', 'Action,Platformer,2D', 'tbd']], ['Crossing Souls', '70', ['Feb 13, 2018', 'T', 'Devolver Digital', 'Action Adventure,General', '6.1']], ['H1Z1', '70', ['Feb 28, 2018', 'T', 'Daybreak Games', 'Action,Action Adventure,Third-Person,Shooter,Arcade,Survival', '4.5']], ['Dandara', '70', ['Feb 6, 2018', 'Raw Fury', 'Action,General,Platformer,2D', '6.2']], ['The Council - Episode 2: Hide and Seek', '70', ['May 15, 2018', 'Focus Home Interactive', 'Adventure,General', '8.3']], ['39 Days to Mars', '70', ['Apr 25, 2018', "It's Anecdotal", 'Action,Puzzle', '4.5']], ['State of Decay 2', '69', ['May 22, 2018', 'M', 'Microsoft Game Studios', 'Action Adventure,Open-World', '4.9']], ['Pure Farming 2018', '69', ['Mar 13, 2018', 'E', 'Techland', 'Simulation,Virtual,Career', '7.7']], ['Age of Empires: Definitive Edition', '69', ['Feb 20, 2018', 'T', 'Microsoft Game Studios', '4.7']], ['Inked', '69', ['Apr 26, 2018', 'Starbreeze publishing AB', 'Adventure,General', '7.9']], ['We Were Here Too', '69', ['Feb 2, 2018', 'Total Mayhem Games', 'First-Person,Adventure,3D', 'tbd']], ['Antigraviator', '69', ['Jun 6, 2018', 'Iceberg Interactive', 'Racing,Futuristic,Arcade', '3.8']], ['Lost Sphear', '69', ['Jan 23, 2018', 'E10+', 'Square Enix', 'Role-Playing,Japanese-Style', '6.9']], ['Rust', '69', ['Feb 8, 2018', 'Facepunch Studios', 'Action Adventure,Historic,Survival', '6.0']], ['Smoke and Sacrifice', '69', ['May 31, 2018', 'Curve Digital Games, Curve Digital', 'Action Adventure,General', 'tbd']], ['Empires Apart', '68', ['Mar 29, 2018', 'Slitherine', 'Strategy,Real-Time,General', 'tbd']], ['Trailblazers', '68', ['May 8, 2018', 'Rising Star Games', 'Racing,Futuristic,Arcade', 'tbd']], ['WARTILE', '68', ['Feb 8, 2018', 'Playwood Project', 'Strategy,Turn-Based,Tactics', 'tbd']], ['TT Isle of Man', '68', ['Mar 27, 2018', 'E', 'Bigben Interactive', 'Racing,Arcade,Automobile', '4.6']], ['The Thin Silence', '68', ['Apr 27, 2018', 'Nkidu Games Inc.', 'Adventure,General', '7.3']], ['Battlezone: Combat Commander', '68', ['Mar 1, 2018', 'Rebellion', 'Strategy,Real-Time,General', 'tbd']], ['Genital Jousting', '68', ['Jan 18, 2018', 'Devolver Digital', 'Miscellaneous,Party / Minigame', '7.5']], ['LEGRAND LEGACY: Tale of the Fatebounds', '67', ['Jan 24, 2018', 'SEMISOFT', '6.8']], ['Zwei: The Arges Adventure', '67', ['Jan 24, 2018', 'XSEED Games', 'tbd']], ['Conan Exiles', '67', ['May 8, 2018', 'Funcom', 'Action Adventure,Survival', '6.4']], ['Sea of Thieves', '67', ['Mar 20, 2018', 'T', 'Microsoft Game Studios', '4.1']], ['Fallen Legion+', '66', ['Jan 5, 2018', 'YummyYummyTummy', 'tbd']]]
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I run this code: TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len() for line 11

Comment: @littlejiver No `len` function is being called in this code. Please post your code which is raising this error.

Comment: see update but all I did was copy the code you provide